# Json.NET - supported JSON schema draft version

Tags: json.net

This is driving me nuts, but I can't find which IETF draft version of JSON schema is supported by Newtonsoft's Json.NET.  Am I correct in assuming from http://json.codeplex.com/discussions/43333 that it's still draft version 3?  I'd like to be sure....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried contacting the developer every which way... No dice.  After a weekend looking at the project source at https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json it's pretty obvious that IETF v3 of Json Schema is *partially* supported.  The properties that are/aren't supported for schema generation and validation aren't enumerated in project docs, either.  Sighs abound.

On the bright side, it'd be fun to build a Json Schema generator/validator that's actually current and documented....